# How to run wordcount program in hadoop 2.7.1 with 2.6.1 eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I've installed hadoop 2.7.1 in my windows 10 environment and have placed eclipse 2.6.0 plugin jar in eclipse(luna).After running the following code I am getting errors.

**Mapper Function**

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

public class TokenizerMapper
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

 IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
 Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
             ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
 word.set(itr.nextToken());
 context.write(word, one);
}
}
}
```

**Reducer Function**

```java
package Exp2;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import java.io.IOException;
public  class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
     IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

**Driver function**

```java
package Exp2;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;




public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(Exp2.WordCount.class);
        // TODO: specify a mapper
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        // TODO: specify a reducer
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

        // TODO: specify output types
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        if (!job.waitForCompletion(true))
            return;
    }

}
```

my execution console begins with

> 16/04/13 21:40:57 DEBUG conf.Configuration: Handling deprecation for dfs.namenode.edits.dir

and ends up with error messages like

```java
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree.isAvailable(WindowsBasedProcessTree.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ResourceCalculatorProcessTree.getResourceCalculatorProcessTree(ResourceCalculatorProcessTree.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.initialize(Task.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any remedies ???